# Moving commits to a new branch and removing those commits from master

Tags: git

So i'm new to branching, so far i have only a master branch. I would like to move specific existing commits that i have made from master to a new branch and remove those commits from master. An example:

```
current master:     c1-c2-c3-c4-c5-c6-c7-c8-c9
```

**After creating newbranch:**

```
master:    c1-c2-c5-c6-c9
                        \
newbranch:              c3-c4-c7-c8
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+move+commits+different+branch

Comment: In your case you create a new branch at `c4`, cherry-pick `c7` and `c8` into that branch, and remove these commits from master using interactive rebase.